# How to get the GCP zonal failure event / activity logs in cloud logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataproc, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I would like to create a dataproc cluster automatically in the event of zonal failure by triggering cloud function by zonal failure logs . Since I haven't seen/experienced zonal failure in GCP so for , so how can i get the sample activity / event log of zonal failure in GCP to create a log sink with pub/sub to trigger cloud function.

If any other best practice to mitigate zonal failure of dataproc clusters, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering your question, but I hope it captures your intent: Dataproc has a built in [Auto Zone placement](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/auto-zone) for that purpose.

Comment: Yes I'm leveraging this auto zone feature while creating through cloud function. But I'm planning to keep the created dataproc cluster for atleast 8 hours to run my jobs. What if zonal failure happens during that time window , for example lets say 9am to 5pm .

Comment: Any specific failures you are expecting? Depend on the specific job you are running, you can potentially write any job failure log to GCS bucket and then write a cloud function to trigger cluster creation? similar example would be - https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-function#create_a_cloud_function